# https redirect with exception

Tags: https

I have a problem with my program connecting with magento api. it doesnt connect with https.

i was thinking maybe i could use htaccess redirect to force to use http.

does it make sense?

i was trying something like that but didnt work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/api/v2_soap 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^api/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have rally big problem with that. Please help.

Kuba